# The most frequent integer value from set of intervals

Tags: algorithms, intervals

What is the fastest way to get one of the value from set of intervals which occurs most frequently?

For example if I have interval (0, 3) and (2, 4) the most frequent value can be 2 or 3.

Comment: This is a dump of a problem, not a question. If you have a specific question regarding the wording of the problem or about concrete steps in your own attempts at solving the problem, feel free to edit accordingly and we can reopen the question. See here for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the answer to your question will have a technique similar to this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/9676296/477522